# Mysql query appears to be working but still get error?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

I am running the following and it appears to be extracting the data from the array as the error contains all the data I have queried, so im not sure why I am getting an error for  :

```
<?php
$user = $_POST[cf_id];
$form = $_POST[uid];
$date = date("d-m-Y"); 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead SET '".$form."' = '".$date."' WHERE cf_id = '".$user."' ")
or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

The error I am getting is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''185cfb5654aacf3038e3f26491f227356b5d768f' = '30-12-2011' WHERE
>   cf_id = '32'' at line 1

As you can see the data is being pulled in, so not sure I have a syntax error somewhere ?

Comment: post your query plz so we can check the error. sorry about the english

Comment: Can you provide a snip of the code running the query, or where the query is being constructed?

Comment: Can you post the table structure of hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead?

Comment: Hi, the query is coming from chronoform, it posts to my database, then in the onsubmit code I have the above code to log when a form is being sent

Comment: Also, you really need to look into prepared statements.  This is a very dangerous snip of code.  If you don't believe me, try to figure out what would happen if someone posted a value of "'; DROP TABLE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead;"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert the values from the array into the column from the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682300/insert-the-values-from-the-array-into-the-column-from-the-array)

Answer (score 3):

If ``$form`` is a column, don't use quotes (') but rather accents (`). (so make it ``$form``)

Comment: Just FYI: Usually in a programming situation they're referred to as backticks rather than grave accents.

Comment: does that apply for $user too as it is also a column, it equals column cf_id

Comment: No, $user is not a column but rather a value OF the column of that perticular row. \`cf_id\`, though, _is_ a column.

Answer (score 0):

$10 says you have an apostrophe in your string and didn't bother escaping it, leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
<?php
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[cf_id]);
$form = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[uid]);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string(date("d-m-Y")); 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead SET '".$form."' = '".$date."' WHERE cf_id = '".$user."' ")
or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that what you're calling $form is being used as a column name.  Since you are populating it from a post parameter named UID, I'm assuming this is not correct.  What you likely want is something more along the lines of:

```
"UPDATE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead SET `date` = '".$date."' WHERE cf_id = '".$user."' and `uid` = " . $form;
```

I'm sure that's not exact, but it just doesn't make any sense to use a UID as a column name.